# sails.js custom layout is not working in production environment

Tags: sails.js

I'm using sails 0.11.0 and in controller custom layout in not working when i start server with --prod flag(its working without prod flag). e.g

Controller:

```js
index: function (req, res) {
  return res.view('administrators/index', {
    layout: 'user'
  });
},
```

Comment: This is also not working:

res.locals.layout = "user";
res.view("administrators/index");

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
res.locals.layout = "user";
res.view("administrators/index");
```

Comment: i've tried this. but still not working in production.